# VMWare_Player Kernel Module problems Ubuntu 14p04

Tags: 14.04, vmware-player

I just started learning with Ubuntu and wanted to install the vmware Player. It worked fine until I start the installed VMWare_Player Verson 4.0.6.

As soon as I start it a window pops up and tells me:

"Before you can run VMWare, several Modules must be compiled and loaded into the running kernel.

```
Kernel Headers 4.2.0-34-generic
```

Kernel headers for Version 4.2.0-34-generic were not found. IF you installed them in a non default path you can specify the path below.  Otherwise refer to your distribution's documentation for Installation instructions and click Refresh to search again in default locations"

Can someone help me and tell me what to do ? :)
Thanks :)

Cheers
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

Are you seriously running VMPlayer 4?

There are a couple of requirements to load and compile VMWare, and they can be satistied from the terminal window (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>).  The command

`sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic`

will provided the needed components.

I would suggest, however, that you should visit the [VMWare Website](https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/12_0) and download player version 12.1.0.  You will find that VMPlayer 4 does need several patches to operate correctly, and I do not know if those patches are still available.

Comment: Thanks that worked just fine with V12.1.0 ;)
I'm using Xubuntu now atm 

got another question, maybe you have an idea why that is not working
after I created to VMs on the computer I can' access the internet anymore.. not from xubuntu or from one of the Windows VMs

Comment: @Chill0ut Are you using a bridged connection or a NAT connection?  If you are running NAT, then your Ubuntu will also need to be able to operate as a router.

Comment: thanks ! 
it's working now after i changed the cat 5e cable xD

but thank you for all your help!!!